# Casting to get ID from selected doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, dropdownbox

I try to get a category-id from the selected item in the dropdownlist. I fill the dropdownlist with a foreach loop (using a list).

This is the code that I am using to get the ID:

```
    protected void dropDownCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        Category category = (Category)ddl.Items[ddl.SelectedIndex];
        int CatID = category.CategoryID;
    }
```

The code above doesn't work, and gives me this error:

```
Error   2   Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'XXXXXX.classes.Category'
```

But when I use the similar code for a listbox, the code below works!

```
    protected void listBoxCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lb = (ListBox)sender;
        Category category = (Category)lb.Items[lb.SelectedIndex];
        int CatID = category.CategoryID;
    }
```

Why does this piece of code work for a listbox and not for a dropdownlist?

Thanks!

Comment: are you filling both in the same way?

Comment: Yes, the one with the listbox is in a c# form application, and that dropdown is in asp... Does that matter?

Answer (score 1):

`System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList` has a `ListItemCollection` as its Items property, which is a list of `ListItem`, an object that has a text and a value properties.

while

`System.Windows.Forms.ListBox` has an `ObjectCollection` as its Items Property, which is basically a list of objects

so when you add an item to a drop down list you are adding a List Item, which can't be converted to your type, i will need to see your drop down list filling code to know what you are storing in each item.

however when you add an item to a list box, you are adding a object, so if in each item you add an instance of your class then it can be converted back by casting.

Comment: Assuming you had a collection of category (such as List<category>) you could probably adapt the code above without a great deal of difficulty - something like "var category = categories.Where(c => c.CategoryID == lb.Items[lb.SelectedIndex].Value).SingleOrDefault();" This will obviously depend on how you have bound the drop down list.